# How can I create a parent html element by appending sub element from an object?

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I need to return a line which will be created based on a list.
Here is the object,

```
 searchCriteria: {
  op_company: "039",
  doc_type: "ALL"
}
```

and in my UI, i need to show it as a paragraph with bold values. So the hard coded code would be like below

```
<p>Download request for op_company: <b>{searchCriteria.op_company}</b>, doc_type: <b>{searchCriteria.doc_type}</b></p>
```

But the object(searchCriteria) will be changed based on the user request. So I tried like below.

```
const getSearchCriteria = (criteria) => {
 let searchCriteria = []
 searchCriteria.push('Download request for')
 Object.keys(criteria).forEach((key) => {
   if(criteria[key] !== '') {
     searchCriteria.push(` ${key}: ${criteria[key]},`)
   }
 });
 return searchCriteria;
}

return (
  <p>
        {getSearchCriteria(searchCriteria).map((item) => <span key = {item}>{item}</span>)}
  </p>
);
```

here i'm getting the expected output. But I can't get the value as bold (highlighted). Is there another way to directly deal with html elements?

Comment: Yeah, this question makes no sense.

Comment: Why? I need the values as Bold. But since i have used string array, i can't find a way to achieve it. So i am searching for a solution.

Comment: Instead of an Array, are there any ways to use a html element, so that i can push sub elements one by one into it

Comment: the bold is controlled by css style. If you want to use it directly in React, you can try the prop `style`, `<div style={{ fontSize: 'bold' }}>Hello World</div>`